# Creating a Microsoft Access database to input student marks and view final results

Tags: ms-access

I've been tasked to create a student database for my work at a College.

The database will be used for calculating a students marks. This will involve adding a students name and ID, then adding the modules they will take and finally entering the marks for each module.

I've created the tables, query and form so far to show the students modules however I'm really struggling on the last part on how to enter marks for the module.

One of the main problems is also the weighting of each mark as some modules have 1, 2 or 3 components: e.g. Coursework 50% Exam 50% so I will have to also incorporate this into the module marks.

So far I've created 3 tables:

**StudentInfo** - 
StudentID,
FirstName,
LastName

**Modules**
ModuleID,
ModuleTitle,
CourseCode,
Component1,
Weight1,
Component2,
Weight2,
Component3,
Weight3

**Enrolment** - 
ID
StudentID
ModuleID

I've created a Query which includes:

StudentID,
ModuleID,
FirstName,
LastName,
ModuleTitle

And also a Form from the StudentInfo table with a Subform of the Enrolment table.

I'm a beginner in Access to any help or advice would be much appreciated!

Happy to email the database if someone does want to have a look/make changes.

Many thanks,

Sarah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've done most of the hard work already, you just need another table to hold the marks. There are plenty of different ways you could structure this, but as an example, you could copy the design from your **Enrolment** table and extend it to include marks for each component.

It might look something like this:

**Marks** - ID, StudentID, ModuleID, Component1Mark, Component2Mark, Component3Mark

Then to get your weighted results for ModuleID **X** (assuming a 30% weighting is entered as 0.3) you would query it like:

```
select marks.StudentID, (module.Weight1 * marks.Component1Mark) + 
  (module.Weight2 * marks.Component2Mark) + (module.Weight3 * marks.Component3Mark)
  from module
  inner join marks on module.ModuleID = marks.ModuleID
  where module.ModuleID = X
```

Comment: Sure thing - if that has resolved your question, please mark this as the answer.